# CSS rules to write html while sending emails from command line in Go

Tags: html, css, email, go

I am trying to write HTML with some CSS to send it in an email. The email is sent through Go command line execution. But its returning errors regarding CSS properties while sending email.

I am getting errors for properties like, `background: rgb(255, 255, 255)` or `padding` for some of its properties it returns "not found" error in terminal.

`<div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; background: #ffffff; font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #313131">`

Above is a chunk of html and css properties I am using.

Following is the code to send email through command line:

```
package utils

import(
    "bytes"
    "html/template"
    "os/exec"
    "fmt"
)

type EmailRequest struct{
    EmailTo      string
    EmailSubject string
    EmailBody    string
}

func (request *EmailRequest) EmailSend(notificationTemplateData interface{}) (bool, error) {    
    subject, errParse := ParseTemplate(request.EmailSubject, notificationTemplateData)
    body, errParse    := ParseTemplate(request.EmailBody, notificationTemplateData)
    if errParse != nil{
        return false, errParse
    }
    err := ExecuteCommand("echo \""+body+" \" | mail -s \"$(echo \" "+subject+" \nMIME-version: 1.0;\nContent-Type: text/html;charset=\"UTF-8\";\n\")\"  "+request.EmailTo)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }

    return true, nil
}

func ParseTemplate(templateHtml string, data interface{}) (string, error) {
    var body string
    t, err := template.New("test").Parse(templateHtml)
    if err != nil {
        return body, err
    }
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

    if err = t.Execute(buf, data); err != nil {
        return body, err
    }
    body = buf.String()
    return body, nil
}

func ExecuteCommand(command string) error{
    cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c",command)

    var out bytes.Buffer
    var stderr bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr

    err := cmd.Run()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + stderr.String())
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println("Result: " + out.String())
    return nil
}
```

I have an editor where a customer can configure its custom template. Obviously, the customer can add any CSS properties. So with random properties it will lead to an error.

What I have understood from the above error is that it throws errors for random CSS properties or is there any CSS rules to send email through go command line?

**Edited:**

Following is the Error that I am getting in terminal while running EmailSend() function.

```
sh: 
padding: not found
sh: 
background: not found
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the error? Or can you give the exact message of the error? It is quite unclear now.

Comment: It might be because a double quote `"` in the case code got unescaped to the shell and messing the command to `echo "div style="margin: 0; padding` thus `padding` is recognized as a command.

Comment: What does `ExecuteCommand` do, and why are you using shell `echo` instead of just using the `Stdin` on the command directly in Go? This code seems almost like a port of a bash script, which is going to be very frustrating to get right in Go.

Comment: Please show exactly what you do and what the exact error is.

Comment: @Adrian I want to  send email on some action in the system like on creation of new account. For that I can not directly hit the command on the command line, so I am doing it through ExecuteCommand().

Comment: @Adrian I have updated the code for ExecuteCommand(). I forgot to include this.

Comment: You're using Go, to call `sh`, to call `echo`, to pipe input into `mail`. My point is, you could just use Go to call `mail`, and send the body via the `exec.Command`'s Stdin, which would vastly reduce complexity, reduce the potential for bugs, reduce the need for escaping, and likely improve performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Adrian mentioned in above comments, I was using go command itself to parse html and css properties. Following is a much simplified solution to send email through command line with html and css.

```
func (request *EmailRequest) EmailSend(notificationTemplateData interface{}) (bool, error) {    
    subject, errParse := ParseTemplate(request.EmailSubject, notificationTemplateData)
    body, errParse    := ParseTemplate(request.EmailBody, notificationTemplateData)
    if errParse != nil{
        return false, errParse
    }
    err := ExecuteMailCommand("mail -s \"$(echo \" "+subject+" \nMIME-version: 1.0;\nContent-Type: text/html;charset=\"UTF-8\";\n\")\"  "+request.EmailTo, body)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }

    return true, nil
}

func ExecuteMailCommand(command string, body string) error {
    cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", command)
    cmd.Stdin = bytes.NewBufferString(body)

    stdout, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)
        return err
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", stdout)
    return nil
}
```

In the above code the function ParseTemplate will remain the same.

Thanks!